# Is there a way to clear model tables using Laravel artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

During development, for testing purpose, I sometimes need the tables related to one of the model clear. For example, I may have a `team` model with `testers`, `coders`, `managers`, `projects` and `offices` models linked with foreign key. I would like to clear all of these tables to test my create team function.

Currently I do that by,

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

It works, seeder adds back data I needed for the testing environment, but it also clears all other unrelated tables. Also, it drops and recreate table and therefore it is slow.

I know I can write a function for that, but it seems a bit overkill. Is there other artisan command for me to do this action?

Comment: if its just for testing then you should be using `setUp` method and `tearDown` methods. You can always write an artisan command which will specifically do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this artisan command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=TeamSeeder
```

where `TeamSeeder` is the name of the seeder class which you have created to seed a specific table.

Make sure you truncate the table in that seeder class, before seeding.

This command will not recreate the table and which is not even required in your case.

Hope this will help.